# Выделить найденное слово в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Есть SearchView в ActionBar и список RecyclerView. Как сделать чтобы слова, которые ищутся в RecyclerView выделялись коричневым фоном.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс Адаптера

```
public class BludoAdapter extends RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<BludoAdapter.BludoViewHolder> {

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    int lenght;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
        void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    //Конструктор класса адаптера
    public BludoAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setupCursorAdapter(null, 0, R.layout.item, false);
    }

    //Возвращает ViewHolder для работы с адаптером
    @Override
    public BludoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new BludoViewHolder(mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent));
    }

    /**
     * Moves the Cursor of the CursorAdapter to the appropriate position and binds the view for
     * that item.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BludoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Move cursor to this position
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);

        // Set the ViewHolder
        setViewHolder(holder);

        // Bind this view
        mCursorAdapter.bindView(null, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());

    }

    //ViewHolder для отображения данных на экране
    public class BludoViewHolder extends RecyclerViewCursorViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public final TextView txtBludo;
        public final TextView txtRecept;
        public final ImageButton btnfavorite;
        String favorites;
        int id;

        public BludoViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            txtBludo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBludo);
            txtRecept = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecept);
            btnfavorite = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnfavorite);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnfavorite.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            // переменные id, like переносим в поле класса-холдера, чтобы был доступ из всех методов
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda._ID));
            favorites = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda.COL_LIKE));
            String bludo  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda.COL_BLUDO));
            String recept = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda.COL_RECEPT));
            txtBludo.setText(bludo );
            txtRecept.setText(recept);
            // конструкцию с if-else упрощаем

            if (favorites.equals("1")) {
                btnfavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
            } else {
                btnfavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //int position = getAdapterPosition();
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnfavorite:
                    mItemClickListener.onFavoriteButtonClick(id, favorites.equals("1"));
                    break;
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(id);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setFilterLength(int lenght) {
        this.lenght = lenght;
    }

    public int getLenght() {
        return lenght;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, BludoAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private Spinner spinner;
    RecyclerView rvList;

    DBHelper db;

    private int currentLoader;
    final private static int LOADER_RUSBLUDA = 0;
    final private static int LOADER_ZARBLUDA = 1;

    BludoAdapter bludoAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        db = new DBHelper(this);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        rvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,
                layoutManager.getOrientation());
        rvList.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, R.layout.spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        bludoAdapter = new BludoAdapter(this);
        rvList.setAdapter(bludoAdapter);
        bludoAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putString("filter", "");

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_RUSBLUDA, bundle, this);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ZARBLUDA, bundle, this);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int loadID, long l) {
                getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(loadID).forceLoad();
                currentLoader = loadID;
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, id+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite) {
        String table;
        String fav;
        String toast;
        int currentLoader;

        if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            table = DBContract.Bluda.TAB_BLUDARUS;
            currentLoader = LOADER_RUSBLUDA;
        } else {
            table = DBContract.Bluda.TAB_BLUDAZAR;
            currentLoader = LOADER_ZARBLUDA;
        }

        if (isFavorite) {
            fav = "0";
        } else {
            fav = "1";
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBContract.Bluda.COL_LIKE, fav);
        long newRowId = db.database.update(table, values, DBContract.Bluda._ID + "= " + id, null);
        if (newRowId == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(currentLoader).forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        String filter = bundle.getString("filter");
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        bludoAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        bludoAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        Cursor cursor;
        DBHelper dbHeler;
        final int loaderID;
        String filter;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper dbHeler, int id, String filter) {
            super(context);
            this.dbHeler = dbHeler;
            loaderID = id;
            this.filter = filter;
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor onLoadInBackground() {
            switch (loaderID) {
                case LOADER_RUSBLUDA:
                    cursor = dbHeler.getRusBluda(filter);
                    break;
                case LOADER_ZARBLUDA:
                    cursor = dbHeler.getZarBluda(filter);
                    break;
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }
    private void refreshCursor(String str) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putString("filter", str);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(currentLoader, bundle, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                bludoAdapter.setFilterLength(newText.length());
                refreshCursor(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Текст");
            try
            {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Поделиться приложением"));
            }
            catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужна реализация самого адаптера и фильтра в нем, по картинке может быть много вариантов решений не подходящих в конкретных случаях

Comment: Добавила в вопрос класс адаптера и MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку фактически нужно всего лишь выделить несколько начальных букв в списке (по длине поисковой строки), то реализация должна быть довольно простой:

1. В адаптере делаем метод, как `setFilterLength(int length)` (простой сеттер, присваивающий значение полю класса), через который будем передавать в адаптер длину строки для поиска (сколько символов выделить)
2. в `bindCursor()` холдера реализуем само подсвечивание части строки от начала до значения, полученного в методе из пункта 1.

   ```
   @Override
   public void bindCursor(Cursor cursor) {
       ...
       String bludo  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda.COL_BLUDO));
       Spannable boldText = new SpannableString(bludo);
       int searchLength =  getLength();
       if (searchLength > bludo.length()) searchLength = bludo.length();
       boldText.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, searchLength, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       txtBludo.setText(boldText);
       ...
   }
   ```
3. При вводе поискового слова в адаптер через метод пункта 1 передаем длину этого слова.

   ```
   txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
               {
                   bludoAdapter.setFilterLength(s.toString().length());
                   refreshCursor(s.toString());
               }
               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {}
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
           });
   ```

PS: вроде все, но надо потестировать, а мне сейчас негде.

Comment: Я в вопросе обновила оба класса. создала геттер и сеттер для поля length адаптера. Только я не поняла как в методе onBindViewHolder сделать подсвечивание. Писала так, Spannable text = new SpannableString(holder.txtBludo.toString());
        text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, getLenght(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        holder.txtBludo.setText(text); но не получилось

Comment: хотела пока что выделить жирным часть текста

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать подсвечивание в onBindViewHolder()

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна добавил про подсвечивание

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось.. Вы в ответе писали что в onBindViewHolder  нужно делать подсветку и я мучилась с этим, а оказывается нужно было bindCursor

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна ну по логике там, где биндятся данные на айтем :), обычно это в `onBindViewHolder()`, но в вашей реализации `CursorRecyclerView` это вынесли в отдельный метод.Кстати стоит добавить проверку, чтобы длина поисковой строки не была больше длины самого слова.

Comment: Спасибо большое